# How to perform .reduce on Hive List flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have a **Hive Object** as such:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'cartHiveModel.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class CartModel extends HiveObject {
  // for the product title
  @HiveField(0)
  late final String title;
  // for checking the store id
  @HiveField(1)
  late final String storeID;
  // fot the product image
  @HiveField(2)
  late final String image;
  // for the discounted price
  @HiveField(3)
  late final int price;
  // for the original price
  @HiveField(4)
  late final int originalPrice;
  // for the quantity.
  @HiveField(5)
  late final int quantity;

  CartModel({
    required this.image,
    required this.originalPrice,
    required this.price,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.storeID,
    required this.title,
  });
}
```

and when I try to calculate the Total amount by doing

```
var list = Hive.box<CartModel>('cartModel').values;
                list.reduce((value, element) => value.price + value.price);
```

It gives me a runtime error as such:

```
The return type 'int' isn't a 'CartModel', as required by the closure's context.
```

**What I want:** I want to calculate the total amount in the list and return the whole sum as an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `reduce` is the type of the list you're reducing. You're returning an `int` with the addition, but it expects a `CartModel` to be returned.

Instead, you can `map`/`reduce`, where `map` first creates a list of `int`s (the `price` property):

```dart
list.map((item) => item.price).reduce((sum, price) => sum + price);
```

Or you can use `fold`:

```dart
list.fold(0, (sum, item) => sum + item.price);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer matt :)